# Rank using multiple columns and within groups in R

Tags: r, data.table, rank, group, mutate

I want to rank values within groups using two attributes. In theory `frank` in `data.table` should be able to do this, but I am running into a snag where the function does not accept two columns when put into the `%>%` syntax or in the `data.table` syntax to split into groups.

Using the `mtcars` dataset, I am trying to order by cyl and disp within two dummy groups. I can order the data within groups using `order` as suggested in another post (that I can't track down) but I cannot set a method to deal with ties in ranks. I can also use `frank` to order by cyl and then disp but I cannot get that function to do within the groups.

```
data(mtcars)

mtcars<-as.data.table(mtcars)%>%select(cyl, disp, gear)
mtcars$gr1<-rep(c("fast", "slow"), 16)
mtcars$gr2<-rep(c("red", "blue"), each=16)
```

This is the code that I am trying to use but which fails but I do not understand the hints in the error message:

```
mtcars%>%group_by(gr1, gr2)%>%
  arrange(gr1, gr2, .by.group=TRUE)%>% #by.group to keep within groups : may not be helpful for frank
  mutate(ranks=frank(-cyl, -disp, na.last=TRUE, ties.method="min"))#orders by cyl and then by disp

#Error in `mutate()`:
#  ℹ In argument: `ranks = frank(-cyl, -disp, na.last = TRUE, ties.method = "min")`.
#ℹ In group 1: `gr1 = "fast"`, `gr2 = "blue"`.
#Caused by error in `frankv()`:
#  ! x is a single vector, non-NULL 'cols' doesn't make sense
#Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.


#works but only uses cyl
    mtcars[, list(ranks= frank(-cyl,  na.last=TRUE, ties.method="min")), 
                                by=list(gr1, gr2)]
 #fails   
    mtcars[, list(ranks= frank(-cyl, -disp,  na.last=TRUE, ties.method="min")), 
                     by=list(gr1, gr2)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the `?frank` help page, it does not accept multiple vectors as input as you are trying to use it. It either accepts (a) a single vector or (b) a list, data frame, or data.table as the first argument, along with the column names (or a vector of quoted column names or indices).

From `?frank`:

> **Arguments**
>
> `x` A `vector`, or `list` with all its elements identical in length or `data.frame` or `data.table`.
>
> `...`
> Only for `lists`, `data.frames` and `data.tables`. The columns to calculate ranks based on. Do not quote column names. If `...` is missing, all columns are considered by default. To sort by a column in descending order prefix "`-`", e.g., `frank(x, a, -b, c)`. `-b` works when `b` is of type character as well.

Note that `...` works *"**only** for for `lists`, `data.frames` and `data.tables`."*

You don't want to rank a single vector, which means you need to use option (b) - give `frank` the data.table as its first argument, and then specify the columns. To do this by group in `data.table` we use `.SD`. (I don't think this interface will play nicely with `dplyr::group_by`.)

Here's an all `data.table` version of my interpretation of your code. You haven't provided expected output, so I can only hope it's what you want.

```
mtcars[, result := frank(.SD, -cyl, -disp, na.last = TRUE, ties.method = "min"), by = .(gr1, gr2)]
mtcars
#    cyl  disp gear  gr1  gr2 result
#  1:   6 160.0    4 fast  red      6
#  2:   6 160.0    4 slow  red      7
#  3:   4 108.0    4 fast  red      8
#  4:   6 258.0    3 slow  red      4
#  5:   8 360.0    3 fast  red      2
#  6:   6 225.0    3 slow  red      5
#  7:   8 360.0    3 fast  red      2
#  8:   4 146.7    4 slow  red      8
#  9:   4 140.8    4 fast  red      7
# 10:   6 167.6    4 slow  red      6
# 11:   6 167.6    4 fast  red      5
# 12:   8 275.8    3 slow  red      2
# 13:   8 275.8    3 fast  red      4
# 14:   8 275.8    3 slow  red      2
# 15:   8 472.0    3 fast  red      1
# 16:   8 460.0    3 slow  red      1
# 17:   8 440.0    3 fast blue      1
# 18:   4  78.7    4 slow blue      7
# 19:   4  75.7    4 fast blue      8
# 20:   4  71.1    4 slow blue      8
# 21:   4 120.1    3 fast blue      7
# 22:   8 318.0    3 slow blue      2
# 23:   8 304.0    3 fast blue      4
# 24:   8 350.0    3 slow blue      1
# 25:   8 400.0    3 fast blue      2
# 26:   4  79.0    4 slow blue      6
# 27:   4 120.3    5 fast blue      6
# 28:   4  95.1    5 slow blue      5
# 29:   8 351.0    5 fast blue      3
# 30:   6 145.0    5 slow blue      3
# 31:   8 301.0    5 fast blue      5
# 32:   4 121.0    4 slow blue      4
#     cyl  disp gear  gr1  gr2 result
```

Thanks to Jamie's comment, we can construct a `list` on the fly of the ranking columns which we can do within a `dplyr` pipeline:

```
## using list() with data.table
mtcars[, result := frank(list(-cyl, -disp), na.last = TRUE, ties.method = "min"), by = .(gr1, gr2)]

## using list() with dplyr
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(gr1, gr2) %>%
  mutate(result = frank(list(-cyl, -disp), na.last=TRUE, ties.method="min"))
```

Comment: Not sure it's necessary to include .SD. I think all you need is `frank(list(-cyl, -disp), ...)`

Comment: Good point - and that would be an easy way to make it work with `dplyr`.